# Servicemix as service remote debugging

Tags: debugging, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I am running ServiceMix as service using Karaf-wrapper.exe. This exe file uses karaf-wrapper.conf file for configuration. I enabled remote debugging in this conf file. Also I created a environment variable KARAF-DEBUG with value TRUE. but still I am unable to connect it with IntelliJ. System displays "Could not open connection: Connection refused"

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Properties
#********************************************************************
set.default.KARAF_HOME=..\servicemix
set.default.KARAF_BASE=..\servicemix
set.default.KARAF_DATA=..\servicemix\data

# Java Application
wrapper.working.dir=%KARAF_BASE%
set.JAVA_HOME=c:\tools\java\jdk1.7.0_67
set.M2_HOME=c:\\tools\apache-maven-3.0.3
wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java

wrapper.java.mainclass=org.apache.karaf.shell.wrapper.Main
wrapper.java.classpath.1=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/karaf-wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=%KARAF_HOME%/lib/karaf.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=%KARAF_HOME%/lib/karaf-jaas-boot.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.4=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/karaf-wrapper-main.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/

# Application Parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
#wrapper.app.parameter.1=

# JVM Parameters
# note that n is the parameter number starting from 1.
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Dkaraf.home="%KARAF_HOME%"
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Dkaraf.base="%KARAF_BASE%"
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dkaraf.data="%KARAF_DATA%"
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Dkaraf.startLocalConsole=false
wrapper.java.additional.6=-Dkaraf.startRemoteShell=true
wrapper.java.additional.7=-Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/endorsed;%JAVA_HOME%/lib/endorsed;%KARAF_HOME%/lib/endorsed"
wrapper.java.additional.8=-Djava.ext.dirs="%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/ext;%JAVA_HOME%/lib/ext;%KARAF_HOME%/lib/ext"
wrapper.java.additional.9=-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m

# Uncomment to enable jmx
#wrapper.java.additional.n=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1616
#wrapper.java.additional.n=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
#wrapper.java.additional.n=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

# Uncomment to enable YourKit profiling
#wrapper.java.additional.n=-Xrunyjpagent

# Uncomment to enable remote debugging
wrapper.java.additional.n=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE
wrapper.java.additional.n=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.initmemory=4096

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.maxmemory=4096


#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logging Properties
#********************************************************************
# Format of output for the console.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.console.format=PM

# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO

# Log file to use for wrapper output logging.
wrapper.logfile=%KARAF_DATA%/log/wrapper.log

# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM

# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=10m

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=5

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows Properties
#********************************************************************
# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=Servicemix

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.name=Servicemix

# Display name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=Servicemix

# Description of the service
wrapper.ntservice.description=Apache Servicemix 5.x

# Service dependencies.  Add dependencies as needed starting from 1
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=

# Mode in which the service is installed.  AUTO_START or DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START

# Allow the service to interact with the desktop.
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false
```

Comment: some more details on how you did configure it that way. For example how does the wrapper.conf look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's very easy to fix, 
just make sure you replace the n with the right number.

since your last numbered entry is:

```
wrapper.java.additional.9=-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

you need to set the debugging to:

```
wrapper.java.additional.10=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE
wrapper.java.additional.11=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..this is great help